# Magento 2 data migration custom handler?

Tags: magento2, custom, data-migration, data-migration-tool

We are working on data migration using Magento 2 data migration tool. We would like to know how to write a custom handler for customer Id (or) product id.

Could you please advise did any work on this.

Thanks